# How to access a variable inside a .blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a js file that declares a component's data like so

```
data() {
    return {
        registerForm: $.extend(true, new SparkForm({
            hasCoupon: false,
        }), Spark.forms.register)
    }
}
```

and a blade file that tries to access `hasCoupon` like so

```
@if(!$registerForm.hasCoupon)
  @include('spark::auth.register-billing')
@else
  @include('spark::auth.register-coupon')
@endif
```

But this throws the error

> Use of undefined constant hasCoupon - assumed 'hasCoupon'

How can I access this variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the if statement is PHP and therefor you can't access data like you would in Javascript object via the dot `.` operator, use the arrow `->` operator instead to access PHP object properties

```
@if(!$registerForm->hasCoupon)
  @include('spark::auth.register-billing')
@else
  @include('spark::auth.register-coupon')
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Tricks maybe help you.

```
<script>
  if(!registerForm.hasCoupon){
    @include('spark::auth.register-billing')
  }else
    @include('spark::auth.register-coupon')
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(!$registerForm['hasCoupon'])
  @include('spark::auth.register-billing')
@else
   @include('spark::auth.register-coupon')
@endif
```